# Running into a conflict with in my form with related models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, model

I have a form where a user adds a new item, and as part of this they choose a category for the item.  The item can be a deposit or a bill, so I want two different lists they can choose from for categories since they are split up the same way.  Here is my ledgeritem and itemcategory models

```
class Ledgeritem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :amount, :bankaccount_id, :deposit, :itemcategory_id, :name, :processed, :transactiondate

  attr_accessor           :balance
  attr_accessible         :balance

  belongs_to  :bankaccount 
  belongs_to  :itemcategory

end

class Itemcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :deposit, :itemcategory_id, :name, :user_id

  has_many  :ledgeritems
end
```

I have this in my controller.  I originally had it in my model, but moved it to the controller to see if that was the problem.

```
@bill_categories = Itemcategory.all.where("deposit = 0")
@deposit_categories = Itemcategory.all.where("deposit = 1")
```

This is how I'm using it in the form

```
<%= f.label :itemcategory_id %><br />
<%= f.select :itemcategory_id, @bill_categories %>
```

And here is the error I'm getting

```
can't convert Symbol into Integer
```

I'm pretty sure it has to do with the format of my f.select, I just can't figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide options to the `f.select`. You can use [options_from_collection_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select) for that:

```
<%= f.select :itemcategory_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@bill_categories, 'id', 'name') %>
```

That will provide options that have a `value` set to the `id` of the objects in `@bill_categories` and the text that is displayed will be the `name` property of the objects in `@bill_categories`.

Comment: Ah, I knew it was something simple like that.

Comment: Are you sure it's on that line? I'm not sure whether there's an additional issue elsewhere (perhaps in the definition of your `form_for`), but this options_from_collection_for_select solution will save you from an error in the future. :)

Comment: I double checked and the error actually shows on this line in the controller

Comment: @bill_categories = Itemcategory.all.where("deposit = 0") deposit is a tintint in the database

Comment: The `all` portion is unnecessary and probably causing your error. Try `@bill_categories = Itemcategory.where("deposit = 0")`

Comment: It shows several layers of the error, the other end of the error, actually the first place it shows is this line in the Itemcategory model - has_many  :ledgeritems

Comment: Found the issue, it was completely unrelated to what I had up there.